# Help with regex

Tags: apex, code, regular-expressions

I have a string with the following format: "01/12 : Some random comment here. 12/12 : Another comment.".

I want to extract the following data using regex (or some other way):

- Date 1: 01/12
- Comment 1: Some random comment here.
- Date 2: 12/12
- Comment 2: Another comment.

The number of (date, comment) pairs is variable. I was trying the following regex:

```
String my_string = '01/12 : Some random comment here. 12/12 : Another comment.';
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile('(\\d{2}/\\d{2}[^\\d]+)*'); 
Matcher m = regex.matcher(my_string);
system.debug(m.matches());
system.debug(m.groupCount());
system.debug(m.group(1));
```

But this code returns a match with only 1 group count which is "12/12 : Another comment.". What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Ok I was able to get something better with this regex '(\\d{2}/\\d{2}\\s?:?\\s?[^\\d]+)' and using .find() method from Matcher class, thanks to the tip in a deleted answer here. But still I'm getting two strings which I will need to split up again between date and comment. I can work with this, but if someone has a better solution, I would like to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Matcher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) class supports a `find()` method which attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern. Implementing a While loop allows us to repeatedly add your results to a collection.

```
String my_string = '01/12 : Some random comment here. 12/12 : Another comment.';
List<String> pairs = new List<String>();
List<String> formattedPairs = new List<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile('(\\d{2}/\\d{2}\\s?:?\\s?[^\\d]+)');
Matcher m = regex.matcher(my_string);

while (m.find()) {
    pairs.add(m.group());
}
```

Once we have our collection of split pairs, we can then iterate through each and do some string manipulation to obtain the correct format.

```
Integer i = 1;
for(String s : pairs) {
    String s1 = 'Date' + i + ': ' + s.substringBefore(':').replace('\"', '') + 'Comment' + i + ': ' + s.substringAfter(':').replace('\"', '');
    i++;
    formattedPairs.add(s1);
}
```

Although this will result in a final list of formatted values, I believe there is an alternative solution with greater efficiency. Im just unsure of that solution.

Comment: @MauricioOliveira I have updated this post.

Comment: Thanks @TSmith, I have done something similar to that. Using find() made it easier indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use capturing groups more effectively.

```
String my_string = '01/12 : Some random comment here. 12/12 : Another comment.';
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile('(\\d{2}/\\d{2})\\s+:\\s+([^\\d]+)*'); 
Matcher m = regex.matcher(my_string);
while (m.find())
{
    system.debug(m.group());
    system.debug(m.group(1));
    system.debug(m.group(2));
}
```

Note that I changed your pattern expression somewhat. You want two capture groups, and you don't really care about capturing the colon character. The above script yields the following logs:

> [6]|DEBUG|01/12 : Some random comment here.
>   [7]|DEBUG|01/12
>   [8]|DEBUG|Some random comment here.
>   [6]|DEBUG|12/12 : Another comment.
>   [7]|DEBUG|12/12
>   [8]|DEBUG|Another comment.

So as you can see, `m.group()` or `m.group(0)` returns the entire captured expression. `m.group(1)` returns everything between the first set of parentheses (date expression). `m.group(2)` returns everything between the second set of parentheses (comment expression).